# How to find character in element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way of finding a specific character in an element in a list. The program is meant to check if the first letter of the input words are the same, and to output 'True' if so:

```
inp = input('Enter words: ')
inp2 = inp.split()
if inp2[0][len] in inp2[0][len]:
  print('True')
```

and to have it do something like this:

```
Enter word: beetle btleee
True
```

or:

```
Enter word: beetle tleeeb
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the first character of the first word with `inp2[0][0]` against first character of the second word with `inp2[1][0]`. You can do this easily with the equals `==` operator.

```
if inp2[0][0] == inp2[1][0]:
    print("First letters are equal") # or True
else:
    print("First letters are not equal") # or False
```

For safety you should also ensure `inp2` has 2 words. You can use an `if` condition to do this:

```
if len(inp2) == 2:
    if inp2[0][0] == inp2[1][0]:
        print("First letters are equal")
    else:
        print("First letters are not equal")
else:
    print("Please enter two words")
```

Also printing `"True"` is a not necessary since you can use reserved boolean types `True` and `False`. You can have a look at [Built-in Constants](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/constants.html#built-in-constants) from the documentation for more information.

Another approach is using tuple unpacking with `try..catch` exception handling:

```
inp = input('Enter words: ')

try:
    word1, word2 = inp.split()

    if word1[0] == word2[0]:
        print("First letters are equal")
    else:
        print("First letters are not equal")

except ValueError:
    print("Please enter only 2 words")
```

Which catches a `ValueError: too many values to unpack` exception if more than two words were entered, or `ValueError: not enough values to unpack` if less than 2 words were entered. You can have a look at [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) from the documentation for more information on how to handle errors/exceptions.

You could also wrap the word comparison code inside a function that returns `bool`:

```
def is_equal_first_letters(word1, word2):
    if word1[0] == word2[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Alternatively with more terse syntax:

```
def is_equal_first_letters(word1, word2):
    return word1[0] == word2[0]
```

Then call the function in the rest of your code:

```
inp = input('Enter words: ')

try:
    word1, word2 = inp.split()
    print(is_equal_first_letters(word1, word2))

except ValueError as ex: 
    print("Please enter only 2 words")
```

You can have a look at this [Python Functions](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function) tutorial to learn more about functions.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are asking for:

```
input1 = input('Enter the two words: ')
input2=input1.split()
def function(input2):
    if input2[0][0]==input2[1][0]:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')

function(input2)  #and then call the function.
```